# conda env variables not working as expected

Tags: python, conda

I have a conda environment that wasn't properly pulling the values of my shell env vars, via:

```
import os
os.environ.get(<env var>)
```

I realized that was likely because the Conda env had access to different env vars so I found and applied:
`conda env config vars set <var_key>=<var_value>`
After reactivating with `conda activate <env>`, running `conda env config vars list` shows the environment variables now active for the environment.

However, I still am getting a `None` when I run `print(os.environ.get("$<env_var>"))`

Any ideas?

Comment: `print(os.environ.get("$<env_var>"))` the dollar there doesn't seem right.

Comment: @cel as a matter of fact, it was not!  Thank you!  That's the solution.

Comment: What is the difference between `print(os.environ.get("$<env_var>"))` and what @cel wrote, `print(os.environ.get("$<env_var>"))` ?

Comment: @AMC nothing. What they wrote wasn't what they suggested.  Getting rid of the `$` did it.  For some reason, I thought it was required.  Brain fart.

Comment: @SamDillard _Brain fart._ Same, I thought they meant "there's something wrong with the dollar sign".